# Update list item from tasks in parallel block

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

In SP Designer 2013, my workflow has a parallel block with two assign a tasks actions in it. The block doesn't complete until both tasks have completed so how can I update my list to show if one of the tasks is complete? I know how to do this sequentially but I need to assign them simultaneously. Is there a way to do this without parallel tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parallel block, instead of adding your two task actions, first add two step blocks. Then, add one task to each step. After each task, add an additional action to update the list. If required, add an additional action after the parallel block to update the list to indicate that both tasks were completed.

Comment: Thank you! This works